# how to show ckeditor with basic toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

I am showing a ckeditor in my webpage using `class="ckeditor"` way. How can I configure my ckeditor to just show a basic toolbar. Here I found the sample page for showing a basic toolbar but not getting from documentation how to show that.

http://ckeditor.com/demo

check the Custom toolbar tab and see the first sample which has a very basic type of toolbar, how can I show it?

here is my code

```
<body>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" id="description" rows="5" cols="15"></textarea>
</body>
```

I want to show basic toolbar for all instances of ckeditor of my website.

Comment: Have you googled `how to configure ckeditor`?

Comment: what is editor1? I am showing ckeditor using <textarea class="ckeditor"></textarea>

Answer (score 50):

If you use Basic it will show all Toolbar, So use this

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
   ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],
   '/',
   ['Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough','-','Undo','Redo','-','Cut','Copy','Paste','Find','Replace','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Print'],
   '/',
   ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
   ['Image','Table','-','Link','Flash','Smiley','TextColor','BGColor','Source']
] ;
```

Comment: there is nothing that says Basic... you may Customize if you understand the Array of Toolbar... your requirements says the Basic or full or etc... you may can name your own toolbar...

Answer (score 20):

If you put the two previous answers together, you will have the full solution.  The first thing is to add the options in the 'config.js' file in your 'ckeditor' folder.

```
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.skin = 'bootstrapck';
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.toolbar_Full =
        [
            { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
            { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
            { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
            { name: 'forms', items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                'HiddenField' ] },
            '/',
            { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv',
                '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
            { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
            { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe' ] },
            '/',
            { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
            { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
            { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] }
        ];

    config.toolbar_Basic =
        [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink','-','About']
        ];
};
```

Then add the call to the 'Basic' config in the HTML file.

```
            <textarea id="ckeditor"></textarea>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor',
                        {
                            toolbar : 'Basic', /* this does the magic */
                            uiColor : '#9AB8F3'
                        });
            </script>
```

That should be all you need, and obviously do not forget to call the 'ckeditor.js' file in your html file.

Comment: I applied the above answer to my own project, and got it to work. More importantly, this answer led me to what I think is an even better answer, and that it the use of the custom config.js. See: "Using a Custom Configuration File" on this page: `http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration` I cut out everything except for `{ name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'clipboard', 'undo', 'spellchecker' ] }`

Comment: I don't want the same toolbar for every instance of ckeditor... i tried making this assignment in my own code before I instantiate the editor in question, but it didn't work.  Where do I need to add this code?

Answer (score 14):

You need to set a specific configuration on launch.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'description',
    {
        toolbar : 'Basic', /* this does the magic */
        uiColor : '#9AB8F3'
    });
</script>
```

`description` is refering to the `id` of the editor on your website.

**Interesting links:**

- [Configuration settings](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations)
- [Toolbar configuration](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar)
- [General CK Docs](http://docs.cksource.com/)

Comment: what is editor1? I am showing ckeditor using <textarea class="ckeditor"></textarea>

Comment: That's the ID of the editor in your HTML, because you can have multiple editors on the same page. I guess `editor1` is the default value if you copy the code from the CKEditor website. -- Your Editor on your page should have the ID like: `<div ... id="editor1" class="ckeditor" ...>`

Comment: still not working, when to call this .replace method and where?

Comment: @coure how are you initializing CKEditor? The `class` thingy alone won't do, you have to be using some JavaScript at some point...

Comment: @coure2011 you need to call the editor's script for example in the `<head>` of your website. -- Updated the answer with your editor id `description` for clarification.

Comment: You're missing the real problem.  ckeditor defines 'Basic' as everything.  He wants a minimal toolbar, which is what most people mean when they say "basic".  So you're providing the opposite of the correct solution.

Comment: @wmil I told him to set a specific configuration and linked the documentation for the configuration, because it's not clear what elements are wanted. You do recognize, that this answer refering to `basic` configuraiotn is five months older than the other one describing a specific configuration? -- It may have changed in the newer CKEditor versions, but there is a difference between `full` and `basic` configuration...

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED FOR 2018:**

Those helpful tykes at [CKEditor](http://nightly.ckeditor.com) have only gone and created an online editor that you can customise to your hearts content! It's a nightly build so a static URL is of no use to you - navigate from http://nightly.ckeditor.com to the basic configurator option then select the **TOOLBAR CONFIGURATOR** button.

Copy and paste the generated content in to the ivoryckeditor bundle's config.js file (Web folder) and it should work without needs any of other file changes.

I built the following simple layout to show cut & paste operations and :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
    { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
    { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
    { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
    { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
    { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
    { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
    { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
    { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
];

config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck in this issue but after so many  trials i got solution of my problem:

use this in ckeditor.rb:-

Ckeditor.setup do |config|
  require "ckeditor/orm/active_record"
  config.cdn_url = "//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.12.1/**full**/ckeditor.js"
end

you can also change full to basic, standard or classic as per your requirement

best of luck